# How to make sure that the character length/set length in a field is set to a particular number when using php?

Tags: php, html

I have a form field which requires only numbers to be filled and the user should enter 8 digits in order to submit the form. What is the command that I need to use when writing my php/html code?

Tried using max but that also means I can enter 0 and still submit the form. Any thoughts on how to set a length so that you are forced to enter those number digits?

```
<label>Line Number</label>
 <input type="number" name="Line" class="form-control" max="999" placeholder="Enter Line Number" value="<?php echo $Line; ?>" />
```

I expect the answer to have 3 digits entered. Nothing less and nothing more. So can be 000 to 999. So even if you want to say 0 you need to enter 000 to submit the form.

```php
if(empty($_POST["Line"])) { 
    $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Please Enter Line Number</label></p>'; 
} else { 
    $Line = clean_text($_POST["Line"]); 
}
```

Comment: ```PHPcode looks like this : 
if(empty($_POST["Line"]))
 {
  $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Please Enter Line Number</label></p>';
 }
 else
 {
  $Line = clean_text($_POST["Line"]);
 }

Comment: If you'd want to use regex, the pattern would be `^\d{` *n* `}$` for exactly *n* digits. Eg with `preg_match` for 3 digits: `if(preg_match('~^\d{3}$~', $_POST["Line"])) {` /* success */ `}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All input-values in the `$_POST` array are strings. So just check the length of the string, by doing `strlen($_POST["Line") != 3`. You can also check if the string is purely numeric by using `ctype_digit()`.

```php
if (empty($_POST["Line"])) { 
    $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Please Enter Line Number</label></p>'; 
} elseif (strlen($_POST["Line") != 3) {
   // Do something here, it was not 3 characters long
} elseif (!ctype_digit($_POST["Line"])) {
   // The string does not contain only numbers
} else { 
    $Line = clean_text($_POST["Line"]); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the included [filter functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php).

Like this:

```php
if(
    // check if `line` input is submitted
    filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'line') &&

    // checks and converts to INT, returns false if not in an int format
    filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'line', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) && 

    // checks if the submitted int has a length of 8 - without entered whitespaces
    8 === strlen(trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'line', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)))
) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using html `pattern` to make it lighter

```
<input type="text" name="Line"  pattern="[0-9]{3}" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Line Number" value="<?php echo $Line; ?>"/>
```